# AssemblyFileVersion causing build to fail

Tags: tfs, msbuild, compact-framework

When I try to build my project, I get the following error:

```
error : Unable to update the AssemblyFileVersion for c:\builddir\MyProject\AssemblyInfo.cs: No stub entry for AssemblyFileVersion was found in the AssemblyInfo file.
```

I found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/828f6b53-81c0-498a-9d02-0c6437aa835a) article, which implies that a "stub" property is required.  So, in my AssemblyInfo.cs, I tried to specify one:

```
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0")]
```

However, it isn't recognised.  I finally came across [this](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/assemblyfileversion-on-cf.aspx) article, which says that you can't use the AssemblyFileVersion property with the CF.  The targets file used by the build script is also used for building other, non CF projects, and needs to update the FileVersion for them.

Is it possible to put something in the AssemblyInfo.cs file, the target file or the build script that stops this from being an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, something like this:

```
#if !(WindowsCE || PocketPC)
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0")] 
#endif
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, because AssemblyFileVersion isn't recognised for the CF

Comment: Which is why the #if is there.  If it's a CF app, WindowsCE or PocketPC will be defined and that line will not be compiled.

Comment: You can really put it anywhere.  I typically put it in the AssemblyInfo.cs file where Studio puts the original, or if I'm sharing version info across multiple binaries then I put it in a common, shared file.

Comment: But that doesn't solve the problem - the CF project will still not have that stub?

Comment: The I don't understand the problem.  Doing what is above eliminates the error you're seeing and allows your code to compile.  I do it all the time.  If you've got some other issue, you need to explain it further.  For example if you want to support that attribute and have it do something (like you need your assembly and file versions to be different) then you could use something like this: http://blog.opennetcf.com/ncowburn/Trackback,guid,e5babf15-ebb3-47b0-b072-957e6f3ccc85.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If using the preprocessor in the manner described in the other answer doesn't work for you, consider putting the AssemblyFileVersion attribute into a separate source file, and conditionally including that source file in the project:

```
<Compile Include="AssemblyInfo.cs" />
<Compile Include="AssemblyInfo.AssemblyVersion.cs"
  Condition="
    '$(TargetPlatform)' == 'WindowsCE' OR
    '$(TargetPlatform)' == 'PocketPC'"
  />
```

I'm not sure if there is already a property you can use in the project file, or if you would need to declare your own (perhaps $(Platform) is used for this?)